# scipy -- how to insert an array of zeros into another array with different dimensions

Tags: python, scipy

If i have an array:

```
myzeros=scipy.zeros((c*pos,c*pos))  , c=0.1 , pos=100
```

and an array:

```
grid=scipy.ones((pos,pos))
```

How can i insert the zeros into the grid in random positions? The problem is with the dimensions.

I know that in 1d you can do:

```
myzeros=sc.zeros(c*pos) # array full of (zeros)
grid=sc.ones(pos)         # grid full of available positions(ones)
dist=sc.random.permutation(pos)[:c*pos] # distribute c*pos zeros in random
                                        # positions
grid[dist]=myzeros
```

I tried something similar but it doesn't work. I tried also: `myzeros=sc.zeros(c*pos)`, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways, but the easiest seems to be to first convert the 2D grid into a 1D grid and proceed as in the 1D case, then convert back to 2D:

```
c = 0.1
pos = 100
myzeros=scipy.zeros((c*pos,c*pos))
myzeros1D = myzeros.ravel()
grid=scipy.ones((pos,pos))
grid1D = grid.ravel()
dist=sc.random.permutation(pos*pos)[:c*pos*c*pos]
grid1D[dist]=myzeros1D
myzeros = myzeros1D.reshape((c*pos,c*pos))
grid = grid1D.reshape((pos, pos))
```

EDIT: to answer your comment: if you only want a part of the myzeros to go into the grid array, you have to make the dist array smaller. Example:

```
dist = scipy.random.permutation(pos*pos)[:c*pos]
grid1D[dist] = myzeros1D[:c*pos]
```

And I hope you are aware, that this last line can be written as

```
grid1D[dist] = 0
```

if you really only want to set those elements to a single instead of using the elements from another array.

Comment: :Hello, when i run the last command it gives me "grid = grid1D.reshape((c*pos, c*pos))" ..Any ideas?Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what you mean by that, but I have had an error in the last line. Maybe you just forgot to press enter ofter the last line?

Comment: :I had a typo error.It works.But the problem is that i want to insert c*pos zeros into the grid=scipy.ones((pos,pos)).With the above ,it inserts the number of shape of the myzeros array (c*pos *c*pos) into the grid.I can't figure a way to do that!

Comment: :Exactly what i want!Thanks a lot.Also,it doesn't need to be created the myzeros=scipy.zeros((c*pos,c*pos)).It can be done with 1D myzeros.(this goes about my second question).